# NextJS: Handling page links within subpath using rewrites

Tags: redirect, next.js, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use the NextJS rewrites feature to display a Webflow site under a sub path from the domain. For example:

```
e.g.
mysite.com/wf/features => mywebflow.com/features # Redirected
mysite.com/stuff/thing => mysite.com/stuff/thing # Normal next routing
```

I'm using the `rewrites` feature in next.config, with:

```
  {
    source: "/wf/:path*",
    destination: "https://mywebflow.com/:path*",
  },
```

This *does* work initially. For example if I go to `/wf/features` it shows `https://mywebflow.com/features`. However, when I click any links in the page it goes to `/page`, without the `wf` prefix which means that NextJS treats it as a "normal" route and doesn't use the rewrite.

I thought perhaps I could use the [has](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#header-cookie-and-query-matching) feature but I'm not sure how it works with `type: "host"`.

What is the correct approach for this?

Thanks!